# Trying to understand Maybe Monads using LiveScript

Tags: javascript, monads, option-type, livescript

I am trying to understand monads better.
Is this minimal implementation of a Maybe Monad Correct ?

```
Maybe = (value) ->

    @value = value

Maybe.prototype.ret = -> @value

Maybe.prototype.bind = (fn) ->

    if not (@value is null)

        return fn @value

    @value

Maybe.prototype.lift = (fn) -> (val) -> new Maybe fn val
```

also if this is correct - there is a final function that I am confused about how to generalize.

```
Maybe.prototype.lift2 = (fn) -> (M1, M2) ->

  f = M1.bind ((val1) -> M2.bind (val2) -> fn val1, val2)

  new Maybe f
```

Now how do you generalize this for lift3,lift4.... liftn
Source : http://modernjavascript.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/monads-in-plain-javascript.html

Follow Up Question:

Could you give me a simple example of how to combine the Maybe Monad with another Monad for simplicity
sake lets keep it a Promise with a `.then` method

Since the real usefulness of Monads are transforming them.

Comment: `ret` shouldn't be an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of implementing `Maybe` monad in LiveScript:

```
class Maybe
  ({x}:hasValue?) ->

    # map :: [Maybe a -> ] (a -> b) -> Maybe b
    @map = (f) ->
      if !hasValue then Nothing else Just (f x)

    # bind :: [Maybe a -> ] (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
    @bind = (f) ->
      if !hasValue then Nothing else f(x)

    # toString :: [Maybe a -> ] String
    # note here it's not necessary for toString() to be a function
    # because Maybe is can only have either one these values: 
    # Nothing or Just x
    @show =
      if !hasValue then 'Nothing' else "Just #{x.toString!}"

  # static method
  @pure = (x) -> Just x
```

The constructor takes an optinal `{x}` parameter. `Maybe` in Haskell is implemented by pattern matching on its value consturctors. This funny parameter is a hack around it, because JavaScript (LiveScript) doesn't support SumTypes.

Now we can define `Just` and `Nothing` as:

```
# Just :: x -> Maybe x
Just = (x) -> new Maybe {x}

# Nothing :: Maybe x
Nothing = new Maybe null
```

To test our Maybe, let's define a `safeSqrt` function:

```
# safeSqrt :: Number -> Maybe Number
safeSqrt = (x) ->
  if x > 0 then Just (Math.sqrt x) else Nothing

# operation :: Maybe Number
operation = do ->
  a = Just 4
    .map (x) -> x * -16
    .bind safeSqrt

console.log operation.show
```

This code will print `Nothing`.

`liftM2` is a function that operates on any monad. It needs to know the type of the underlying monad, because it uses `pure` (that in our implementation is a static function):

```
# liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
liftM2 = (monadType, f, m1, m2) -->
  x1 <- m1.bind
  x2 <- m2.bind
  monadType.pure (f x1, x2)
```

Here's how we can use it:

```
# operation :: Maybe Number
operation = do ->
  a = Just 4
    .map (x) -> x * 16
    .bind safeSqrt
  b = safeSqrt 81

  liftM2 Maybe, (+), a, b

console.log operation.show
```

[Code in JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xenomo/edit?js,console)